# Meaning of "Even on nights we can't see the stars, they're up there sparkling away"?

Tags: meaning

Why did it use the word "nights" instead of the word "night" and use the word " on nights" instead of the word "at night or at nights" in the following sentence,

> Even on nights we can't see the stars, they're up there sparkling
>   away.

?

At night, if stars sparkle, we can see the stars. but,
This sentence is interpreted as meaning that if stars sparkle at night, we can not see the stars. Did I misunderstand the sentence?

Does it mean "Because the stars sparkle, we can't see the stars at night" or "Although the stars sparkle, we can't see the star at night' ?

What does "Even on nights" mean?
What does the sentence mean?

source :: A pocket full of kisses

> "Every night, just before the sun goes down, it reaches out with its
>   rays and touches every star in the universe. One by one, the stars
>   light up and shine down upon us. Even on nights we can't see the
>   stars, they're up there sparkling away. No matter how many stars fill
>   the sky, the sun will never run out of light, and its rays will never
>   stop reaching out to them.

Comment: Please provide more context if possible. Where did you find this sentence?

Comment: He is saying, "Even on those nights in which we cannot see the stars (because of cloud cover), the stars are still up there sparkling away."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this sentence, ‘nights’ is used as the plural of night. The exact meaning of ‘[night](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/night)’ can be found here in case you’re unclear.

This sentence means that at night, stars exist and are shining even if you can’t see them when you are looking up into the sky.

Personally, I think that this sentence could be an analogy but it is unclear what the exact analogy is unless the context is provided.